# Latitude + Longitude = city name, React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, google-geolocation

I'm building a React weather app with an API that only accepts a Latitude and Longitude, not a city name.
I'm new to React and am wondering if there's a way to transform the user input (City name) to latitude and longitude so I can call the api.

Thank you!

Comment: Does your question specifically asks about geocoding using Google Maps API?

Answer (score 4):

You should try a geolocation package or api like this one for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package//react-geocode

They've already done the busy work of figuring out that conversion for you.

Comment: If this works, go ahead and close this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are few other Apis I have used for weather applications which use city name
to fetch weather data along with latitude and longitude.you can take a look if it serves your purpose.

1. [Open weather map api](https://openweathermap.org/api)
2. [Accu weather Api](https://developer.accuweather.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to avoid having to learn how to hide the api key but it might be easier to do than to deal with the geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will display user's geolocation.
Please don't hesitate to use values of `lat` and `long`.

```
const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
  const [long, setLong] = useState(null);

  const geolocationAPI = navigator.geolocation;
  const getUserCoordinates = () => {
    if (!geolocationAPI) {
      console.log("Geolocation API is not available in your browser!");
    } else {
      geolocationAPI.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          const { coords } = position;
          setLat(coords.latitude);
          setLong(coords.longitude);
          codeLatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude)
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("Something went wrong getting your position!");
        }
      );
    }
  };
```